# Shall I use 'in' or 'on' or 'during the course'?

Tags: prepositions

I want to refer to an online open course, is it correct to say

> Communism was introduced in/on/during the course

Which one in your opinion is better?

Answer (score 2):

Since such a course happens over a period of time, and we don't know at what point communism was introduced, I would use *during*:

> Communism was introduced **during** the course.

Answer (score 0):

While 'in' looks proper among all three, there's another way (and probably a common way).

> Communism was a *part/module* of the course

That's because when you say something was 'introduced' in the context of some online course, it means it was newly introduced. For instance, you registered for an online course of iOS programming **and** in between, the latest technology of *[Swift](https://developer.apple.com/swift/)* popped up. You can say that the institute then **introduced** Swift ***during*** the course.

On the other hand, if you just want to say that you are acquainted with some topic as you studied it during the course, you may simply say *....was a part of your course...* and it'll work in most of the cases.